# Can't do a REST get request with Angular2 and Firebase database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do a get request with Angular2 and Firebase database. The post request works perfectly well but a get request won't work. I don't know what am doing so wrong.

**Here is my list.component**

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
   notes = []
  constructor(
    private store: Store,
    private noteService: ListingService
  ) {
    
  }
 
 ngOnInit() {
   this.noteService.getNotes()
    .subscribe();

    this.store.changes.pluck('notes')
    .subscribe((notes: any) => { this.notes = notes;  console.log(this.notes)});
  
  }

  onCreateNote(note) {
    this.noteService.createNote(note)
    .subscribe();
  }

  onNoteChecked(note) {
    this.noteService.completeNote(note)
    .subscribe();
  }

  
}
```

**Here is my api.service**

```
export class ApiService {
  headers: Headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json'
  });

  api_url: string = 'https://someapp-94b34.firebaseio.com/';
  constructor(private http: Http) {
 
  }

  private getJson(response: Response) {
    return response.json();
  }

  private checkForError(response: Response): Response {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return response;
    } else {
      var error = new Error(response.statusText)
      error['response'] = response;
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  get(path: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.api_url}${path}.json`, { headers: this.headers })
    .map(this.checkForError)
    .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
    .map(this.getJson)
  }
  
  post(path: string, body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      `${this.api_url}${path}.json`,
      JSON.stringify(body),
      { headers: this.headers }
    )
    .map(this.checkForError)
    .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
    .map(this.getJson)
  }
}
```

**Here is my listing.service**

```
export class ListingService {
path: string = 'notes';
  constructor(private storeHelper: StoreHelper, private apiService: ApiService) {}

  createNote(note: Note) {
    return this.apiService.post(this.path, note)
    .do(savedNote => this.storeHelper.add('notes', savedNote))
  }

  getNotes() {
    return this.apiService.get(this.path)
    .do(res => this.storeHelper.update('notes', res.data));
  }

  completeNote(note: Note) {
    return this.apiService.delete(`${this.path}/${note.id}`)
    .do(res => this.storeHelper.findAndDelete('notes', res.id));
  }
}
```

**Here is my store.ts**

```
export interface Note {
  color: string,
  title: string,
  value: string,
  id?: string | number,
  createdAt?: string,
  updatedAt?: string,
  userId?: string
}

export interface State {
  notes: Array<Note>
}

const defaultState = {
  notes: []
}

const _store = new BehaviorSubject<State>(defaultState);

@Injectable()
export class Store {
  private _store = _store;
  changes = this._store.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged()

  setState(state: State) {
    this._store.next(state);
  }

  getState(): State {
    return this._store.value;
  }

  purge() {
    this._store.next(defaultState);
  }
}
```

**Here is my store-helper.ts**

```
export class StoreHelper {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  update(prop, state) {
    const currentState = this.store.getState();
    this.store.setState(Object.assign({}, currentState, { [prop]: state }));
  }

  add(prop, state) {
    const currentState = this.store.getState();
    const collection = currentState[prop];
    this.store.setState(Object.assign({}, currentState, { [prop]: [state, ...collection] }));
  }

  findAndUpdate(prop, state) {
    const currentState = this.store.getState();
    const collection = currentState[prop];

    this.store.setState(Object.assign({}, currentState, {[prop]: collection.map(item => {
      if (item.id !== state.id) {
        return item;
      }
      return Object.assign({}, item, state)
    })}))
  }

  findAndDelete(prop, id) {
    const currentState = this.store.getState();
    const collection = currentState[prop];
    this.store.setState(Object.assign({}, currentState, {[prop]: collection.filter(item => item.id !== id)}));
  }
}
```

And here is how am injecting the services to my app.module provider index.ts

```
import * as services from './services';
import { Store } from './store';

export const mapValuesToArray = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);

export const providers = [
  Store,
  ...mapValuesToArray(services)
];
```

**And app.module**

```
import { providers } from './index'
providers: [providers, AnimationService]
```

The posting request works just well but the get request doesn't.
**Here is the error I get:**

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>
> Function calls are not supported.
>
> Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 3:33 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol mapValuesToArray in D:/angular2/someapp/src/app/index.ts, resolving symbol providers in D:/angular2/someapp/src/app/index.ts, resolving symbol providers in D:/angular2/someapp/src/app/index.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/angular2/someapp/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/angular2/someapp/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"won't work"*? I don't think anyone really wants to read through all that code to look for all possible problems. Do you have an error message? Or at least some specific misbehaviour?

Comment: I edited and added the error: ``Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda``

Answer (score 1):

The [AoT compiler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) cannot statically analyse the services you are providing, as you are using the `Object.keys` method to enumerate them.

You could solve the problem by adding an export to `./services.ts` that explicitly lists the services:

```
export const SERVICE_PROVIDERS = [
    ServiceOne,
    ServiceTwo,
    ServiceThree
];
```

Your import would then look like this:

```
import { SERVICE_PROVIDERS } from "./services";
import { Store } from './store';

export const providers = [
  ...SERVICE_PROVIDERS,
  Store
];
```

Comment: This takes away the error, but still nothing from the firebase. But posting works just fine! I was wondering whether it has something to do with the type of json ( array or object) returned from the firebase datatbase.

Comment: So that means you are back to saying that it doesn't work. Try the `GET` in your browser; does that work? If there's no error in your code, add some logging. Without that, it will be hard for anyone to help.

Comment: The get in browser returns json in this format: https://someapp-94b34.firebaseio.com/notes.json ``{
"-Ka0he26FB-lgIGG6ne6": {
"color": "white",
"title": "sssss",
"value": "sssssssssss"
}``

Comment: Not for me: `{ "error" : "404 Not Found" }` It looks like you have some sort of auth issue. Seriously though, I am surprised you want to use the REST API in an Angular app. The [web API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/) or [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) would be much easier and you would get the "real time" goodies, too.